# Is there a way in protractor, by which we can iterate through the webelement having the same css and click on the element with matching text

Tags: javascript, automation, protractor

PageObject.js(Select_Organization.js)

```
this.selectOrganization = function() {   
    organizationLocator.each(function(element) {
        FunctionLibrary.getText(element, organizationName).then(function(text) {
            logger.info(text);
            if (text.includes('ImageResizingOrg')) {
                 FunctionLibrary.click(element, organizationName);
            }
        })
    })
};
```

Spec.js

```
it('should be able to select the required organization', function() {
    Select_Organization.selectOrganization();
});
```

Scenario:

I want to store all the elements having the same class name in a list and then iterate through it using for-each loop and click on the element if the text of the elementFinder is same as that required.

Issue I am facing: Due to async nature of the javascript this is not getting handled properly as sometimes stale  element exception is getting thrown. I know the reason which is because all the actions are getting stored in control flow queue.
I just need a solution for this :) Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Use the cssContainingText to select the element - http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.cssContainingText

Comment: @Grasshopper Yes, I agree thats an alternate way to acheive this. My major concern is to solve the problem in the logic I present, is there any way to get this doone

Comment: Use the filter method of element.all - http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter

Comment: @Grasshopper I used it already also map api, but the problem remains the same